# Using NNjoin tool for closest distance between multiple points and multilinestring

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, distance, points-to-line

When I use the NNjoin tool to compute the distance between points (from an CSV file) and a multilinestring (from a shapefile) the tool creates the new layer, but in this new layer it does not take over the attributes of the points in the CSV file and indicates that the distance is 0. Does anyone have any tips on how to make the NNjoin tool work?

Step by step, this is what I've done:
1. I have started a new project and added a shape file with multilinestrings and a CSV file and projected both in EPSG: 4326 WGS: 84.
2. I have saved the CSV file as a shape file
3. Then I've tried to use both the NNjoin tool and the "match attributes based on nearest" to create a new layer, both times the program would run but not calculate any of the distances, but only contain one row from the CSV file with a distance of 0 calculated.

The outcome I am hoping for is a new layer with the attributes from the CSV file with an added column with the distance between the points from the CSV file and the closest located part of the multiline string.

Comment: If you are using QGIS 3.8 or above you can use the native processing tool 'Join Attributes by nearest'. Maybe this fits your needs better.

Comment: Thanks I tried this tool as well. The problem remains, however, that it does excecute the request, but the new joint layer contains only the data categories, but no longer any of the values. Do you have any tips for this@MrXsquared?

Comment: Uhm, for me it does take over the attributes of both layers. Can you include your exact steps taken in your question as well as the expected result on the basis of an example?

Comment: May I ask a) What are your layers CRS? , b)Have you tried exporting the csv point file as shp layer and use that instead? I usually us NNJoin with layers in a projected coordinate system (UTM for instance) and with shp files...as Mr MrXsquared, I use it a couple of days ago and I have attributes from both layers

Comment: Thanks! To answer your questions a) I am projecting my layers in CRS: EPSG 4326 WGS 84 b) I have tried exporting the CSV point file to shp layer, so that does not work. Would you advice me to convert the file into a projected coordinate system, I am not sure how to choose which system to use @GerardoJimenez

Comment: @MrXsquared I have changed my question, would you be willing to have a look again and tell me if you see anything I might have done wrong!

Comment: 1. If you use a unprojected crs like 4326, your join distance will be in degree. So if both layers are nearby it is most likely 0. 2. You said that you reprojected your file and then saved it as shp. Thats why I assume you just set the crs instead of reprojecting it. Can you explain how you reprojected your layers?

Comment: I don't think I did reproject it. I just saved the CSV as a shapefile. Can you advice me in which CRS I should reproject it / how to decide what CRS to use. I am only looking at Africa for my analysis.

Comment: I've now managed to get the distances from the NNjoin, but if I understand you correctly, these will have been in degrees? Can I recalculate this to kilometres or should I first reproject my CRS's to a proejcted coordinate systen @MrXsquared

Comment: The join distance is in CRS units. WGS84 (EPSG:4326) is in degree, so your distance will be in degree as well. If you want meters as units, you need to use a metric CRS. Sorry, for entire Africa I dont have a good one by hand.

Comment: @GerardoJimenez would you have a good metric CRS to use for this?

Comment: If you are working with the whole continent there is ESRI:102022 and ESRI102023, if you are working at the country level you can look for them at https://spatialreference.org/. As MrXSquared said, if you use EPSG 4326 your distances will be calculated in decimal degrees. For instance, a 30 minute distance wll be .5 degrees. Can you tell us where exactly are you trying to use NNJOIN?